# Error with react native and firebase when changing entries in DB manually

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving data from my firebase DB, this had been working perfectly but when I altered the entries in my DB manually I received the below error:

```
Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN
```

**Method pulling data**

```
listenForItems(itemsRef) {
 itemsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
  this.setState({ data: snapshot.val() });
  console.log(this.state.data);
    });
  }
```

The console correctly shows the newly updated object retrieved from firebase.

**Render method**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem
            title={item.title}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
      );
    }
```

The items in the DB had previously been:

[image]

But, when structured as the below image:

[image]

I receive the error.

**Note:** If I change the values back the error disappears. Can somebody tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in this [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html):

> "Firebase has no native support for arrays. If you store an array, it
>   really gets stored as an "object" with integers as the key names".

In summary:

```
// when we send this
['hello', 'world']
// Firebase stores this
{0: 'hello', 1: 'world'}
```

`signposts` is an array of Objects. Since Firebase does not support arrays natively, what it does is creating an object with integer indexes as key names, to behave like an array when consumed.

Therefore, by changing `0` to `test1`, you're trying to set a string (`test1`) as an array index, which should be a number and this is why you get the `out of range index NaN` error.